# httprequest in android fails and exception is null

Tags: android, http-request

I have an HTTP request that throws a `null` exception.

Here's the code:

```
public String updateRounds() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/Prices/CSV2_Round.aspx");

    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", _user));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", _password));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = "";
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler); // it gets
                                                                  // exception
                                                                  // here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage(); // e is null
    }

    return response;
}
```

Anyone has any idea on why this happening?

Comment: Has your application got the UsesInternet permission?

Also try catching the other types of exception that the httpclient can throw instead of the generic type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help.
I've changed the

```
e.getMessage();
```

to

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

And I saw that the exception was about ssl certificate.
So I handled that and now it works.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You have problem in following.

```
String response = "";
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    try {           
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler); //it gets exception here
```

What is responseHandler?

`httpclient.execute` returns `HttpResponse` and you are trying to return it in `response` (which is String).

So Change

```
  String response
```

to

```
HttpResponse response
```

If you really want to return string then add following code.

```
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
       String line = "";
       String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
       }

      bufferedReader.close();  
      return stringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: well i believe this is not very correct. the httpclient does return a string.

Comment: The BasicResponseHandler processes the response and that is what returns the string. So that bit is not wrong.

Comment: The code i pasted here works at my end.so thought of helping you.Thanks :)